# What is Objective-C's msgSendSuper behavior?

Tags: objective-c

Checking the Apple's open source message dispatching code, I notice that the call to super uses a struct holding the instance and a class it should find the superclass method from.

Does this mean that the compiler must explicitly change messages to super by adding the class it is called from?

And given some class tree where C extends B extends A, and all of them implement a method `m` which calls `[super m]`, and we create D extending A at runtime, grabbing C's implementation of `m` to use as D's; will `[d m]` in fact call all of D, *B*, and A's methods `m` instead of just D and A's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading disassembly, the compiler will change a call to super into loading the address of a class from a fixed list, creating a struct with the instance, and calling `objc_msgSendSuper2`.

Because the class references are fixed constants, creating a class tree with methods as specified and calling method `m` on a D object will indeed execute B's implementation of `m` although D does not subclass B.