# How does Ruby dispatch methods when super is called?

Tags: ruby, super, internals, method-dispatch

I'm doing some research into the internals of how methods are called in some object-oriented languages for a hobby project. I have found information about normal dispatch is fairly easy to come by, but calling the "supermethod" of a class's method is a bit harder to understand.

By disassembling Objective-C I have found that the clang will insert references to a particular class, so that in general the superclass that is called by `[super message]` is fixed at compile time for typical method implementation. ([What is Objective-C's msgSendSuper behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18868123/what-is-objective-cs-msgsendsuper-behavior))

I was hoping to understand what the Ruby mechanism is, but didn't find anything searching. I had a glance at the source but couldn't find what I was looking for. Could somebody please explain the internals of Ruby method dispatch for `super` calls in the standard ruby-lang.org implementation?

Comment: Is this the source you were looking at: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Class.html#method-i-superclass ?

Comment: @Niel no, I was looking through `object.c` etc. from the Github repo

Comment: Did you investigate `vm_eval.c`? https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/vm_eval.c starting from line 250

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev looks like the class an object is being evaluated as included as part of the stack frame / calling information of a method, and it looks up the superclass's method from that.

Comment: @Victor: If you 'view source' on the link I sent, you should see relevant section of `object.c` i.e top-level definition of  `rb_class_superclass(VALUE klass)` - not that this answers your question, just trying to verify we are looking at same thing. Yevgeniy's link includes same internal macro(?) `RCLASS_SUPER` which is doing most of the work.

Comment: @NeilSlater Aha, I had not noticed. The vm_eval is more what I'm looking for. Most class-based languages include some sort of superclass reference in the class and the RSUPER macro looks that up. That's pretty clear to me. I was looking for the specific method dispatch functionality. Like given class C inherts from B inherits from A, how does it know which of those it is calling super from when calling a method?

Comment: "so that in general the superclass that is called by [super message] is fixed at compile time for typical method implementation." Actually, that is not true. The *class* that the `[super message]` code is in is fixed at compile time. Its *superclass* is not.

Comment: @newacct I should have written more precisely. The dispatch is fixed, though, in that the struct is makes before calling msgSendSuper uses a class that is fixed at compile time.